# NServiceBus : Identity context in outgoing message mutators

Tags: nservicebus, mutators

NServiceBus 4.4.0

Hi !

I use message mutators for impersonification purpose. Basicaly, I serialize the ClaimsPrincipal.Identity in a JWT token in the outgoing mutator and deserialize it in the incoming mutator to add it to the principal of the NServiceBus host app. (based on this article : http://beingabstract.com/2014/10/serializing-the-claimsidentity/). The problem is that when we're in the outgoing mutator (IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages) the ClaimsPrincipal.Identity doesn't contain all the claims. Only the name. But if I'm looking just before the "Bus.Send" command, I have the correct claims (groups, permissions, etc.).

The outgoing message mutator resides in an outside class, which is referenced by my main project. Here's the code from the outgoing mutator :

```
public class OutgoingAccessMutator : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages, INeedInitialization
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<OutgoingAccessMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }

    public void MutateOutgoing(object[] messages, TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
       if (!transportMessage.Headers.ContainsKey(Common.Constants.Securite.AuthenticationTokenID))
        {
            transportMessage.Headers[Common.Constants.Securite.AuthenticationTokenID] =
                TokenHelper.GenerateToken(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.IdentitePrincipale() as ClaimsIdentity);
        }
    }
}
```

The GenerateToken is in a static helper class in the mutator dll :

```
public static string GenerateToken(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityKey = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Common.Constants.Securite.NServiceBusMessageTokenSymetricKey);
        var inMemorySymmetricSecurityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = identity,
            TokenIssuerName = Common.Constants.Securite.NServiceBusMessageTokenIssuer,
            AppliesToAddress = Common.Constants.Securite.NServiceBusMessageTokenScope,
            Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, now.AddMinutes(5)),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(inMemorySymmetricSecurityKey, Common.Constants.Securite.SignatureAlgorithm, Common.Constants.Securite.DigestAlgorithm)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return tokenString;
    }
```

Then in the incoming message mutator which lives in another process (windows service executable host), I deserialize it :

```
public class IncomingAccessTokenMutator : IMutateIncomingTransportMessages, INeedInitialization
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<IncomingAccessTokenMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }

    public void MutateIncoming(TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {

        if (transportMessage.Headers.ContainsKey(Common.Constants.Securite.AuthenticationTokenID))
        {
            try
            {
                var token = transportMessage.Headers[Common.Constants.Securite.AuthenticationTokenID];
                var identity = TokenHelper.ReadToken(token);
                if (identity != null)
                {
                    identity.Label = Common.Constants.Securite.NomIdentitePrincipale;
                    ClaimsPrincipal.Current.AddIdentity(identity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the identity context is not the same inside the mutator and in the service that sends the message ?

Comment: Also discussed on particular google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/particularsoftware/FpZ2v0sJBEk/3f8kQA6JAAAJ

Comment: Are you using async in any of the calls? calling `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` will create a basic principal with the name claim if one isn't present. I'd confirm code is running on the same thread